# HTTP 500 error at the server?

Tags: php, apache, http, iis

I can run this PHP script well in my local computer, but when
I've tried to run PHP script in the server,

I got his message at the browser.
This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.

Do you have an ideas to solve it ?
I'm running locally in Apache and the server is IIS

Thanks

Comment: why not look at apache logs ??
or php error logs..

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP 500" is a very, very generic error.  it can mean any number of different things.

Q: Have you checked the server logs?  What do they say?

That's absolutely the first place to start.

ADDENDUM 1.11.2012:

Hi -

It sounds like:

1) you *have* PHP installed on the remote, IIS server, and it's working.  Good :)

2) your scripts are also deployed on the remote IIS server, and they run (also good)

3) So you need to "debug".

SUGGESTIONS:

1) Please contact the administrator of the remote IIS server to see if there's ANY way for you to look at the logs.  It's extremely likely the logs can lead you directly to the problem.  It's also important to be able to monitor the logs after your application is in use.  Please see if the administrator can help you.

2) Failing that, you can always put in "printf" debug statements.

"echo" is useful.

Here's a little script that writes to your own log file:

```
<?php
  function PHPDBG ($s)
  {
    // change "/tmp/PHPDBG.txt" to suit your system
    $fp = fopen ("/tmp/PHPDBG.txt", "a");
    $s = date("d/m/y : H:i:s", time()) . ":" . $s . "\n";
    fputs($fp, $s);
    fclose($fp);
  }
 ?>
```

3) Check the following:

a) Make sure your first script *reads* all variables correctly; make sure the values are all the values you expect

b) Make sure it's following the same *code path* you expect

c) Make sure the URL of the second script is correct

d) Try invoking that URL manually, from your browser, to insure it's correct

e) Make sure any session variables are *written* correctly; make sure the values are the values you expect

'Hope that helps ..

Comment: If you can't see the server log, you really can't debug the problem.  At this point, I gotta ask: are you even sure this server has PHP installed?  Can you run a script that just has "phpinfo()", fo example?

Comment: the first php script can run but when this script passing a parameter into another php script, the second php script giving me (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, but if i test the script locally in apache it's working perfecty...why is it ?

Comment: the first php script can run but when this script passing a parameter into another php script, the second php script giving me (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error, but if i test the script locally in apache it's working perfecty...why is it ?

Comment: is it possible, because of date setting at php.ini ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that IIS supports PHP out of the box.  You'll need to enable it. Here's a great guide:

> http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/php2003/

Comment: Broken link. Please try avoid "link only" answers.

Answer (score 0):

> in httpd.conf or httpd-xampp.conf and check if this is accidentally commented out.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5

Try editing this part in your httpd.conf and set AllowOverride All

And also check .htaccess file, hidden .htaccess file in the htdocs folder caused the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have hosted your files in a sub directory on your server, if that is the case open up .htaccess file and add the following line

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /The_Directory_Where_You_Uploaded_The_Files/
```

hope this solves the problem